Callback function не работает в коде телеграм бота на telebot, как можно исправить?
start_panel = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
start_panel.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Администратор', callback_data='admin_call'))

admin_panel = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
admin_panel.row(types.KeyboardButton('Привелегии администратора'), types.KeyboardButton('Правила работы админа'))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_func(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствуйте', reply_markup=start_panel)

#В данной функции клавиатура админа работает
@bot.message_handler(commands=['admin'])
def admin_func(message):
    if message.from_user.id == id_admin:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Вы вошли как админ', reply_markup=admin_panel)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы не админ!')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data=='admin_call')
def callback_message(callback):
    bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Вам выданы права админа',
reply_markup=admin_panel)

#Минимальный рабочий код
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

start_panel = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
start_panel.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Администратор', callback_data='admin_call'))

admin_panel = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
admin_panel.row(types.KeyboardButton('Привелегии администратора'), types.KeyboardButton('Правила работы админа'))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_func(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Здравствуйте', reply_markup=start_panel)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data=='admin_call')
def callback_message(callback):
    bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, 'Вам выданы права админа',
reply_markup=admin_panel)

bot.polling(non_stop=True)

Я по нескольку раз перечитывал ответы на данную проблему, но не нашел ответ, у людей были проблемы в передачи анонимной функции callback.
Проблема в том, что я правильно передаю данные в анонимную функцию, но она все равно не обрабатывается.

Сделайте минимально воспроизводимый пример и если вам никто не поможет, я по позже гляну.

Пример: Пользователь отправляет команду "/start" и пользователю показывается сообщение "Здравствуйте" и снизу появляется кнопка "Администратор", но при нажатие на кнопку ничего не происходит.

@gookoli Минимально воспроизводимый пример означает короткий рабочий код (Вставил, запустил) который повторяет описанную проблему. [mcve]

То что предоставили работает корректно. Более чем уверен у вас есть ещё один обработчик колбеков, который принимает все колбеки, и этот обработчик находится выше предоставленной функции. И в итоге срабатывает общий обработчик и пытается найти нужный колбек, а его и нет. Либо для каждого колбека ставьте корректный обработчик, либо все колбеки обрабатывайте через иф елиф под одним общим обработчиком

В коде я использую пока один обработчик колбеков, который предоставил выше.

Я дополнил вопрос минимальным коротким рабочим кодом. @gord1402

А необходимый апдейт вообще приходит боту? Вы проверяли?

@gookoli как уже написали выше, ваш минимально воспроизводимый пример прекрасно отрабатывает. Так что проблема в чем то другом

@CausonQ, что вы именно имеете в виду апдейта?

@gookoli откройте ссылку https://api.telegram.org/bot{токен бота}/getWebhookInfo заменив "токен бота" на, собственно сам токен. И посмотрите что указано в allowed_updates. callback_query вот это должно присутствовать

@CausonQ, данная ссылка не работает, когда я делаю все по инструкции вылазит ошибка 404.

Значит не так делаешь. Ссылка должна выглядеть так: https:// api.telegram.org/botAAAAAA:BBBBBB/getWebhookInfo Вместо AAAAAA:BBBBBB пишешь токен своего бота
